# Find approximate shape of phase interface gas - solid

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

Find approximate shape of gas - solid phase interface in pT diagram, p=p(T).

chemical potential of solid approximate by
$$\mu_s=-|\mu_s|=const.$$
and chemical potential of gas
$$
\mu_G=Tln(\frac{p\lambda^3}{T})
$$
and
$$d\mu=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial p}\frac{dp}{dT}dT$$

I understand that at the boundary $\mu_S=\mu_G$ and also $d\mu_S=d \mu_G$.
I tried derivations of chemical potentials but couldn't move with it. How do I approach this problem?
Thank you for you response.

Comment: The Clausius-Clapeyron relation (which gives the slope of the P–T curve) is derived [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation).

Comment: @Chemomechanics, thank you for your reply, I understand that I need to use Clausius-Clapeyron relation but the fact that \mu_S is a constant and after derivation is zero is tripping me, can you please extend your answer.

Comment: What's the justification for $\mu_S$ being always constant? If this is an assigned problem, please give the exact problem statement.